# Network camoflage-techniques of hiding networks

Tags: network

How are top secret networks hidden? What are the techniques to make a network hidden from the public?

Comment: What do you mean, exactly? Are you talking about networks that aren't connected to public ones? If so, read no further. Are you talking about encrypted networks? Ones hidden behind firewalls that drop all unauthenticated traffic? Please add some detail to your question to explain what you are trying to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Top-secret networks are "hidden" through the simple expedient of not connecting them to the Internet, typically with measures in place to prevent accidental connection.

Answer (score 0):

Very robust firewalls are commonly used to protect sensitive systems when attaching them to the internet, to protect them from unwanted access or to make them hard to detect (blocking ICMP and other means of scanning are easy to do on a typical firewall). Note that per your question, if you are referring to "Top Secret" as the classification level of a US DoD system, it is far far far away from public view (the internet, or actual prying eyes, etc) so no technological means are necessary; it is protected the old fashioned way, via "guns and bunkers".